# How to disallow query strings in robots.txt

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, query-string

I have following URLs with query parameters:

```
1- https://www.example.com/en/project-information?products_of_interest__c=EVK
2- https://www.example.com/en/sales-network?office_type=commercial
3- https://example.com/en/product-selector?category=Services   
4- https://www.example.com/en/product-selector?form_factor=JODY
```

I want to disallow indexing on above query parameters and I have written following format to disallow above pages that starts with query parameters:

```
Disallow: /*?products_of_interest__c=*
Disallow: /*?office_type=*
Disallow: /*?category=*
Disallow: /*?form_factor=*
```

Are the above in the right format to meet my requirement?

Comment: Have you tried this config? Did it work?

Comment: Which bots do you want to prevent from crawling them?  Not all bots understand wildcards.